# How to calculate number of workdays between two given date

Tags: c++

Ex. if I give `2013-7-1` to `2013-7-7`, there are 5 workdays (Mon-Fri) and so the output should be 5

PS: In this problem holidays are excepted, only consider the weekends.

Does anyone have an idea of implementing this into c++?

Comment: You need a pretty complex algorithm, since "workday" needs to take into account holidays, etc.

Comment: Moreover, there is no algorithm because holidays can move, be added/removed etc. You need a full historical list of holidays in particular country, then it becomes trivial.

Comment: oh, if holidays are also considered, this maybe too complex... Let's just take weekends into account.

Comment: are you expecting for someone to give you his code? because you already got the algorithm, take all days, but weekends.

Comment: There are hundreds of examples of calendar algorithms in C++ on the net...

Comment: If you can count the workdays, you have your own answer. Have you tried something?

Comment: What's with the hate? This site is supposed to be better than sifting through "hundreds of examples on the net."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it isn't commented and I'm also not a professional programmer but here you go:
It compiles and when I run it and type in 1/1/2013/3 and 12/31/2013/3 I get 261 work days for the year. Which if you multiply 365*(5/7) you get 260.7 so it seems to work. When I do 1/1/2013/3 and  12/31/2015/5 I get 783. I also programmed leap year into it all in less than 90 lines.  Also my naming conventions might not be so consistent.  Also I know it's probably bad style to use nested if statements but whatever this was just a quick and dirty thing.

Edit: I decided to make this more ellaborate to practice my own c++ skills, I've provided more functionality to it.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class date{
public:
unsigned days_per_month[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
unsigned month;
unsigned day;
int year;
unsigned week_day;
constexpr static int week_day_callibrator[4] = {1,1,2013,3};
unsigned get_days(){return days_per_month[(month - 1)];};
unsigned get_days(unsigned n){return days_per_month[(n - 1)];};
void leap_year(){
bool temp = false;
if(year%4 == 0)
temp = true;
if(year%100 == 0)
temp = false;
if(year%400 == 0)
temp = true;
if(temp == true)
days_per_month[1] = 29;
else days_per_month[1] = 28;
};
void truncate()
{
if(month > 12)
month = 12;
if(month < 1)
month = 1;
if(day > get_days())
day = get_days();
if(day < 1)
day = 1;
}
date(unsigned m, unsigned d, int y, unsigned wd) : month(m), day(d), year(y), week_day(wd) {leap_year();truncate();}
date(unsigned m, unsigned d, int y) : month(m), day(d), year(y)
{
leap_year();
truncate();
int wdc[4] = {week_day_callibrator[0], week_day_callibrator[1], week_day_callibrator[2], week_day_callibrator[3]};
while(wdc[0] < month || wdc[1] < day || wdc[2] < year)
{ 
wdc[3] == 7? wdc[3] = 1: ++wdc[3];
if(wdc[1] == get_days(wdc[0]))
{
wdc[1] = 1;
if(wdc[0] == 12)
{
wdc[0] = 1;
++wdc[2];
leap_year();
}
else{++wdc[0];}
}
else{++wdc[1];}
}
while(wdc[0] > month || wdc[1] > day || wdc[2] > year)
{
wdc[3] == 1? wdc[3] = 7: --wdc[3];
if(wdc[1] == 1)
{
if(wdc[0] == 1)
{
wdc[0] = 12;
--wdc[2];
leap_year();
}
else{--wdc[0];}
wdc[1] = get_days(wdc[0] - 1);
}
else{--wdc[1];}
}
week_day = wdc[3];
}

date& operator++(){
week_day == 7? week_day = 1: ++week_day;
if(day == get_days())
{
day = 1;
if(month == 12)
{
month = 1;
++year;
leap_year();
}
else{++month;}
}
else{++day;}
}

date& operator--()
{
week_day == 1? week_day = 7: --week_day;
if(day == 1)
{
if(month == 1)
{
month = 12;
--year;
leap_year();
}
else{--month;}
day = get_days(month - 1);
}
else{--day;}
}
inline bool operator==(const date& rhs)
{
if(year == rhs.year && month == rhs.month && day == rhs.day)
return true;
else 
return false;
}
inline bool operator!=(const date& rhs){return !operator==(rhs);}
inline bool operator< (const date& rhs)
{
if(year < rhs.year)
return true;
else if(month < rhs.month)
return true;
else if(day < rhs.day)
return true;
else
return false;
}
inline bool operator> (const date& rhs){return operator< (rhs);}
inline bool operator<=(const date& rhs){return !operator> (rhs);}
inline bool operator>=(const date& rhs){return !operator< (rhs);}
};

unsigned count_work_days(date & a, date & b)
{
unsigned counter = 0;
while(a < b)
{
if(a.week_day != 1 && a.week_day != 7)
{
++counter;
} 
++a;
}
// makes it inclusive
if(b.week_day != 1 && b.week_day != 7)
++counter;
return counter;
}

int main() {
// initializes variables, calls cin to ask the user to input them, varifies the validity of the values and calls the compare function
string temp;
char temp2;
unsigned beginmonth, begindayofmonth, beginyear;
unsigned endmonth, enddayofmonth, endyear;
cout << "enter start date: mm/dd/yyyy" << endl;
cin >> temp;
stringstream stemp(temp);
stemp >> beginmonth >> temp2 >> begindayofmonth >> temp2 >> beginyear;
cout << "enter end date: mm/dd/yyyy" << endl;
cin >> temp;
stemp.clear();
stemp.str(temp);
stemp >> endmonth >> temp2 >> enddayofmonth >> temp2 >> endyear;
date b(beginmonth,begindayofmonth,beginyear);
date e(endmonth,enddayofmonth,endyear);
cout << count_work_days(b,e) << endl;
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write code for this, as I'm sure this is some form of homework (or you are being paid to do this, or something else like that, meaning it's your task to solve the actual problem).

C (and thus C++) has a set of functions in [`<ctime>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/), which allow you to work with time.

Given these, one can take an arbitrary date, make the a `time_t` using `mktime`, and subtract one from the other with `difftime`, giving you a "number of seconds between two `time_t` values. If you convert a `time_t` back to struct `tm`, it will have a "weekday" entry, so you can tell that, for example, 1-July-2013 is a Monday.

Given all this, it should be quite possible to calculate the absolute number of days between two dates, and if you know what day you start on, find out how many Saturdays and Sundays there are in the period.